# Bathroom fan wiring

Tags: electrical, wiring, bathroom, exhaust-fan

I am trying to install a bathroom fan and am having some issues. The sketch below is how I curently have it wired. (blue in the sketch are the white wires) Previousy there was a single switch that controled the light. There were only 2 wires from the switch which I folowed to the high ceiling but not farther. I think they are the hot black from the main circuit and then the black from the switch to the light. Currently, the light works perfect using the top switch, but the fan doesnt turn on. I am not sure what happens to the wires above the high ceiling. I added the white wire between high and low ceiling to connect the fan white to the light white. Am I making a wiring mistake?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: I should have added in my initial description that there was previously a single switch that operated just the light. There were only 2 wires from the switch which I folowed to the high ceiling but not farther. I think they are the hot black from the main circuit and then the black from the switch to the light. Thise 2 are old and wrapped in what seems to be a woven cover. The three wires coming from the fan are new 14/2 that I put in with the white wrap. No conduit that i know of, but I guess there could be above the high ceiling.

Comment: You should still add that to your original description. It doesn't belong in a comment.

Comment: With only 2 original wires you have some issues because unless you pull a new x3 with ground cable you could not add the 2 circuits. And be code compliant.

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring in the boxes involved please? Also, is running replacement cabling between the light and switch an option?

Comment: Ed- is this the sort of thing where if you dont change anything it is ok since it was installed before code required grounding, but if you change anything you have to bring it to current code?

ThreePhaseEel- I dont think running new cable between light and switch is an option because I really don't want to get up above the high ceiling and create more finish work to be done.